# Web Service attempt Giving SoapException, why and what to do?

Tags: web-services, soap

I learned about the basics of making a web service with Visual Studio 2008 ASP.Net + VB. And I got the "Hello World" working, but for some reason I can't get a function method to work the same way without this error, and I can't any info anywhere what to do about it.

Code:

```
*Web Service:*

<WebMethod()> _
    Public Sub logEvent(ByVal userId As String, ByVal userGroup As String)

        'method functions here

    End Sub

*Mainpage Code-behind*

    Protected Sub webrefTester()

        Dim testi As my_dbServer.Service
        testi = New my_dbServer.Service

        testi.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        'have to include this because i use urls instead of local to simulate
        'intended functionality, so there were authorization issues at first

        testi.logEvent("userId_0", "Mgmt Services 2010")

    End Sub
```

As said, the hello world works fine, so I have added the web reference to the solution where I need to use the web service etc etc. I just can't seem to pass parameters for the web service, it always throws a soapexception. I need that for logging info into the database.

Any other tips for a first-timer web service user would be welcome too. Basically my project has me doing a service that can be used for various software to log event information such as visitor types, possible error messages etc.

Thanks again!

Comment: You might want to show us the soap exception as well

Answer (score 0):

It just says SoapException, this is the error message:
"Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object."